# If two matrices are similar to the same diagonal matrix are they similar?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have $P^{−1}AP=D$ and $Q^{−1}BQ=D$. How do I show that A and B are similar. 
I have $QP^{−1}APQ^{-1}=B$ but I am a bit stuck now. I also have the information that $A$ and $B$ have the same characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is enough! You're on tiny step away

Write $C = QP^{-1}$, and notice that $C^{-1} = PQ^{-1}$. Then $B = CAC^{-1}$ :), so A and B are similar! (this, in particular, shows that matrix similarity is a transitive relation)

Comment: Can you explain why $C^{-1} = PQ^{-1}$? I might just be blanking out but this seems like a bit of a jump

Comment: You CHOOSE $C$ that way because, given the hypotheses, that's what you need to show that $A$ and $B$ are similar.

Answer (score 0):

To show $A,B$ are similar we need to find a matrix, say $M$, so that $M^{-1}AM=B$. Notice $Q$ takes $B$ to $D$ and $P$ takes $A$ to $D$. So why not use $P$ to take $A$ to $D$ and then $Q^{-1}$ to take $D$ back to $B$? So the idea would be to try $M= PQ^{-1}$. Then $M^{-1}= QP^{-1}$ and

$$
M^{-1}AM= (QP^{-1})A(PQ{^{-1})= Q(P^{-1}AP)Q^{-1}= QDQ^{-1}= B}
$$

But then $A$ and $B$ are similar.

Answer (score 0):

We have $B=QP^{−1}APQ^{-1}=(QP^{-1})A(PQ^{-1})$ and since $QP^{-1}=(PQ^{-1} )^{-1}$ we are done.